# Telegram wrong URL host

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm making bots. I tried every thing and this my code:

```
def send_photo(chat_id, location , reply_markup=None):
    url = URL + "sendPhoto?chat_id={}&photo={}".format(chat_id,open('1.jpg', 'rb'))
    if reply_markup:
        url += "&reply_markup={}".format(reply_markup)
    print(get_url(url))
    get_url(url)
```

My file is in my .py folder and I double checked every thing, I even used photo telegram id's and url's and I'm still getting:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong URL host"}
```

Comment: Did you try to reach the same url with a browser or maybe with curl ?

Comment: yes i did my friend

Comment: And with curl it works ?

Comment: no, and my url now is my file from the disk

Comment: Can I suggest to download this, try to run and example as it is and the change it to your needs rather than writing from scratch ? https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

Comment: i only have problem in photos, audios and docs are ok

Answer (score 1):

#https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto

```
import requests
import json

token = 'Token'

def send_photo(chat_id, photo, caption='', parse_mode=None, disable_notification=False, reply_to_message_id=0, reply_markup=None):
    with open(photo, 'rb') as file:
        response = requests.post(
            'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendPhoto?'.format(token=token),
            data={
                'chat_id':chat_id, #Integer or String
                'caption':caption, #String
                'parse_mode': parse_mode, #String https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options
                'disable_notification': disable_notification, #Boolean
                'reply_to_message_id': reply_to_message_id, #Integer
                'reply_markup': json.dumps(reply_markup) if reply_markup is not None else reply_markup, #List
            },
            files={
                'photo': file.read()
            }
        )
        file.close()
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return json.loads(response.text)

reply_markup = {
    'inline_keyboard':[
        [
            {'text':'stackoverflow', 'url':'https://stackoverflow.com'}
        ]
    ]
}
print(send_photo('802959264', 'test.png', caption='caption', reply_markup=reply_markup))
```

**This is the output**

```
{'ok': True, 'result': {'message_id': 10, 'from': {'id': 1157936984, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'test', 'username': 'RoomSupervisorBot'}, 'chat': {'id': 802959264, 'firs
t_name': 'milad', 'username': 'milad_dev', 'type': 'private'}, 'date': 1597892647, 'photo': [{'file_id': 'AgACAgQAAxkDAAMKXz3oJ8X-3jkfsP8GgT_oAtOUhUwAArO0MRuwP_BR0owk2ZSqQ
RdwWPEiXQADAQADAgADbQADaNoEAAEbBA', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADcFjxIl0AA2jaBAAB', 'file_size': 8226, 'width': 320, 'height': 180}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgQAAxkDAAMKXz3oJ8X-3jkfsP8GgT_
oAtOUhUwAArO0MRuwP_BR0owk2ZSqQRdwWPEiXQADAQADAgADeAADadoEAAEbBA', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADcFjxIl0AA2naBAAB', 'file_size': 35836, 'width': 800, 'height': 450}, {'file_id': 'AgAC
AgQAAxkDAAMKXz3oJ8X-3jkfsP8GgT_oAtOUhUwAArO0MRuwP_BR0owk2ZSqQRdwWPEiXQADAQADAgADeQADatoEAAEbBA', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADcFjxIl0AA2raBAAB', 'file_size': 78830, 'width': 1280, '
height': 720}, {'file_id': 'AgACAgQAAxkDAAMKXz3oJ8X-3jkfsP8GgT_oAtOUhUwAArO0MRuwP_BR0owk2ZSqQRdwWPEiXQADAQADAgADdwADZtoEAAEbBA', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADcFjxIl0AA2baBAAB', 'fil
e_size': 88002, 'width': 1366, 'height': 768}], 'caption': 'caption', 'reply_markup': {'inline_keyboard': [[{'text': 'stackoverflow', 'url': 'https://stackoverflow.com'}]]}}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Kindly use http url instead of local,
It will work else 
upload the file first and then get the file_id 
then send that file id to the bot.